# My password generator is generating Gamma symbols and fractions. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, passwords, generator

My password generator is generating Gamma symbols and fractions... how  do I fix it?

It works fine sometimes but sometimes it will generate Gamma symbols and fractions.
They want me to put more details in but that's really it...

I was thinking that maybe I could change the type of the numbers to int but I am not super confident that will work.

This is just for fun... I'm trying to learn Java and this piece is something I'm playing with...
Any help that you provider would be great! :-) 
Thanks!

---

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordGenerator 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int length = 10;
    System.out.println(generatePswd(length));
  }
  static char[] generatePswd(int len)
  {
    System.out.println("Your Password:");
    String charsCaps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String nums = "0123456789";
    String symbols = "!@#$%^&*_=+-/€.?<>)";

    String passSymbols = charsCaps + chars + nums + symbols;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    char[] password = new char[len];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        password[i] = passSymbols.charAt(rnd.nextInt(passSymbols.length()));

    }
    return password;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gamma symbols and fractions"? Please post the output you're getting.

Comment: Possibly an encoding issue.

Comment: is the length of output matching with expected length? also keep some sysouts in that for loop and verify individual chars are placed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the `€` in the `symbols` string. It's not an ASCII character, so it's getting encoded to UTF-8 which isn't displayed correctly on your console.

Specifically, `€` is unicode character `U+20AC`, which is encoded in UTF-8 as `E2 82 AC`. The standard DOS character set ([code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) interprets these bytes as the characters `Γé¼`.

To avoid encoding issues, you should stick with printable ASCII characters (0x20 to 0x7E).

Answer (score 1):

It is happens because you have `€` symbol which is non ASCI. If you terminal doesn't support unicode it will bi shown "strange".